# routine address wrong, when re-compiling ancient linux-0.12 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gcc, assembly, linux-kernel, ld

Trying to re-compiling the linux-0.12 on Ubuntu 18.04 (sounds very silly?)
After modifying something of the original code of linux-0.12 (too much to list here for what changed). Finally, the whole thing can be compiled and linked successfully yesterday. Problem now is after entering protect mode, it looks like the address of the routine `setupidt` goes wrong!
Here's the picture: (when debugging using Bochs)
[image: error]
Here's the code snippet: addressing wrong at `call setupidt` 
I suppose reason is gcc option or linker option? Thanks!

```
startup_32:
    movl $0x10,%eax
    mov %ax,%ds
    mov %ax,%es
    mov %ax,%fs
    mov %ax,%gs
    lss stack_start,%esp
    call setupidt
    call setupgdt
    movl $0x10,%eax     # reload all the segment registers
```

Ubuntu 18.04, gcc 7.4.0 ld 2.3
part of the Makefile:

```
AS  =as --32
LD  =ld
CFLAGS  = -m32 -Wall -fstrength-reduce -fomit-frame-pointer \
        -g3 -gdwarf-4 -O0 -fno-stack-protector -fno-builtin #-g3 -gdwarf-2 -m32 
# -fno-defer-pop for fs
# -finline-functions for kernel and 3 sub folder, and lib and mm
LDFLAGS = -m elf_i386 -Ttext 0 -e startup_32#-s -x -M
```

For whole Makefile and all, see https://github.com/meetjoy/exploring_cs/tree/master/0.0

The program entres into protect mode correctly. Linker or gcc options?

Comment: Does `-fno-pie -no-pie` matter here?  The current default of `-fpie -pie` didn't exist when the code and build scripts were written, so they might not account for it.  ([32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)).

Comment: Thanks Peter. This problem fixed after adding -fno-pie to CC, adding -no-pie to LD. Finally I get into the main(). Next addressing error I got today (:>) is when invoking printk() which is defined inside of printk.c under folder kernel. I will try to resolve myself. Will turn to you guys for help if I couldn't. Thanks.